# ReactiveCocoa 3 - bufferWithTime

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I've been bridging to use `RACSignal.bufferWithTime`. As far as I know there is no equivalence of it in RAC 3? Is there a workaround / trick to imitate the behaviour of `bufferWithTime` using RAC3?

My case scenario is that I need to track if the user tapped twice in a given short period (to capture double tap). I basically buffer it with about 0.2 seconds and see if there was more than a single tap. FIY, I cannot use `UIGestureRecognizer` since I use third party object which only exposes a single tap API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `bufferWithTime`, it can be done simply by checking timestamps on each tap. Follow these steps:

1. Create a Signal of tap events on the third party object.
2. `map` the Signal of tap events into timestamps representing the current time *when the tap occurs*.
3. Use `combinePrevious` on the Signal of tap events to create a Signal whose values are a tuple of two timestamps: the first is previous value and the second is the current value.
4. `filter` this signal by subtracting the first value in each tuple from the second value, and comparing whether it meets or exceeds your `0.2`-second threshold.

Whenever the final signal sends a value, a tap occurred within 0.2 seconds of the previous tap.

Comment: Didn't know `combinePrevious` existed. You saved my day. Thank you so much